# Select checkbox and get results from particular id

Tags: php, checkbox

Hi all when user select one check box automatically the check box id results will come from database is it possible?

```
<tr>
        <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" >1.</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $res['profile_id']; ?>" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" >
        <?php echo $sql['profile_product']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" ><span class="WebRupee" style="color:#FF0000">Rs. </span>
        <?php echo $sql['profile_mrp']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" ><span class="WebRupee" style="color:#FF0000">Rs. </span>
        <?php echo $sql['profile_ctc']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" ><span class="WebRupee" style="color:#FF0000">Rs. </span>
        <?php echo $sql['profile_krt']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `Your permalinks structure is undefined. Please set your permalinks structure here: Permalink Settings` is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka 웃 yes what i have to do can u plz tell me.................

Comment: Pekka 웃 iam net to wordpress first time iam doing because of i want to convert my static htm site to wordpress :)

Comment: Click the link it's showing you. I think you can leave the settings on the permalinks page as they are, just click "save" or "OK" or whatever button there is. After that, things should work.